# CS-CART How to Create new Categories though API

Tags: php, api, cs-cart

I would like to create new categories in CS-Cart through its API.

So far I have this code (running it through browser, just for testing):

```php
$cfg = get_config(); //connection to DB

$product_data = array();
$product_data["category"] = "Category Test API";
$product_data["company_id"] = 1;
$product_data["status"] = "A";


//CURL
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'USER EMAIL'.":".'YOUR API:KEY');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $cfg["cscart_store_url"]."api/categories/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    )
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($product_data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

if( !curl_error($ch) ) {
    echo "no error";
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($server_output, TRUE);
}
else {
    echo "error found!!!";
    print_r("Error: ".curl_error($ch));
    return 0;
}
```

There is a documentation here: https://docs.cs-cart.com/latest/developer_guide/api/entities/categories.html.

But I still couldn't make it work although I did not get any errors from `curl_exec`.

Comment: What do you mean by "couldn't make it work"? What happens? What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as I understood, cs-cart API has some required values in order to make an INSERT API call. Thus, the categories should be already be created inside cs-cart dashboard and match them somehow in the PHP script

On the other hand, if you want to UPDAtE a product for example, you could UPDAte only the specified values you send to API call, without the need of sending all the required API values.

Last but not least, there are more than one Authorizations methods to make the call. I used CURL in order to do the API call and there is a parameter `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` which I have added the below code:

```
...
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Basic XXXxxxxXXXXxxxXXXlzLmNvbS5ncjpKejMXXXxxxxXN0Y2MDQxenprbEXXXxxXXXE3Mg==",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
),
...
```

Where Authorization is: Basic base64(user@example.com:API_KEY_taken_from_cscart)

Applying all the above the code and the API worked!

thanks everyone for the help and comments

Answer (score 0):

Your json is well encoded, your header have the Content-Type, i think your problem is your `cscart_store_url` who have a wrong url or your `USERPWD` isn't good (I believe you didnt put `USER EMAIL` in your auth

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking time to answer my question.. I have checked the USER EMAIL and gave permissions.. What do you mean USERPWD isn't good? Moreover, according to doc, cscart_store_url is: https://www.example.com/api/categories
Am I right? But I tried lots of URLs and still nothing.. thanks again

Comment: if you try your requets on Postman, what result do you get

Comment: Hello, still could not understand what is the problem of the API of cs-cart. I have opened a ticket too.. The URL is a simple one https://www.example.com/
I am also trying to insert a product, and still did not get any errors (neither from Curl nor in logs files), but none products are inserted .. ..
I do not know much about Postman and how to create this request there